# Access VBA - Sql Statement : Query Builder in a Listbox; trouble building statement

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm having trouble building a sql statement in a listbox linked to a table - the sql statement:query builder interface is confusing, and I have trouble with sql statements to begin with; but this interface doesn't seem to allow standard sql operands.

I have a checkbox on the same form with the listbox, and when it's checked, I want the filter to be ">0" and when it's not checked, I want the filter off. So the listbox is linked to a table, with columns in the listbox linked to fields, and I used the Rowsource property to add filters from selections on the form after a requery.

I want something like this, only for it to work.

ListBox Column:

Quantity (Field Name)

MasterItemList (Table)

```
> 0 WHEN [forms]![LookUp]![checkstock] = -1

> OR * WHEN [forms]![LookUp]![checkstock] = 0
```

From the Sql Builder:
[image: sql builder]

Currently all I get is "Invalid Syntax" for pretty much anything I try. Hope someone out there is still using Access 2003/2007.  Seems like such a simple thing to drive me insane.

Edited to add:
As is typical, I found a way around the problem by avoiding the syntax altogether.  I created a separate, invisible text box that changes from 0 to -1, and changed the sql builder condition to:

```
<>[forms]![LookUp]![TextStock]
```

Which will eliminate 0 quantity items when textstock = 0, and show everything when textstock = -1

I still have no idea how to put a more complicated conditional search into one of these things, but this works for now.

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is no WHEN keyword in SQL, it's WHERE!

Here is a working example:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call LoadList
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Call LoadList
End Sub

Sub LoadList()
    If CheckBox1 = -1 Then
        List1.RowSource = "Select ItemName from t_Items where InStock > 0"
    Else
        List1.RowSource = "Select ItemName from t_Items"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Edgar; I did first try "WHERE" in the Listbox Sql Query Builder UI and it's also a syntax error. The UI is different than writing the sql out, and I chose it since I'm working with a multiple column list box, and didn't want to code against the 5 other searches in the sql UI. I'll likely have to redo the listbox as a subform linked directly to the table so I can use actual sql statements instead of this UI sql builder in a search (should be faster, too - 1.5 million records takes a bit to load into a listbox), but setting up intermediate textbox did the trick for now. Thanks again.